# Parse Weblog (Omniture) Data -Adobe Analytics

Tags: database, streaming, adobe-analytics, bigdata

I am having a web search log file having Omniture data as below(sample):

1. Each record could contain up to 178 columns
2. These are '|' delimited text files
3. The data consists of 421,266 records

Sample Record

> 1331175664|2012-03-07 19:01:04|2858672213737177245|6917530638790887804|FAS-2.8-AS3|N|0|65.0.176.236|1|0||10|http://www.acme.com/SH55126545/VD55170364|{44491661-134A-492B-A0AC-CE28420721D3}|||||||||||||U|en-US||537|651|1366|Y|Y|Y|2|2|304|bellsouth.net|7/2/2012 20:16:27 3 360|45|41||Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)|48|0|1|38|0|columbia|usa|710|ms|0|0|1|0||||||||0|||||||||||||||||WAPT|||||0|||||||||||212,120||||||||||||||||||||||||WAPT|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||0|||||

In which each value is separated with '|' in file, but i could not find/Understand the Column Names or header for these records.I could identify few column names like IP-Address/Date-Time, but some are difficult to understand.

Please anyone help me to get column Names for each values.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: wherever you got this file from, you should have also received a "header" file that shows the columns names. You are supposed to automatically get this when you export this from Adobe (or receive from ClientCare before it was allowed in interface). So it sounds like someone gave you this file without the accompanying files

Comment: btw here is the main [data column reference](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/reference/datafeeds-reference.html). But the columns themselves you need to get the header file that should have come along with that file you got, to know which columns line up with what

Comment: Thanks for the response @CrayonViolent, would you share me the .......log download link ......and I have gone through the column reference link but that dint help me for to identify all the columns!. Please share me the download link.

Comment: I don't have that file. It is generated by Adobe when you get the file you have now. You will need to contact the person you originally received the file from and tell them there should be other files that came along with the file they gave you.